# ExternalInterface in ActionScript 3 not working in offline mode

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, externalinterface

i have problem. I make Flash Video Player with callback to JS, but have a problem when execute page from localdisk. Flash crash with error:

```
Error: Error #2067: ExternalInterface in this container not available.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/addCallback()
    at Player()[C:\Users\User\SkyDrive\Flash\MediaPlayer\Player.as:112]
    at MediaPlayer_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[MediaPlayer_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:35]
```

Any idea, how execute script offline with ExternalInterface ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should run it on a web server to get ExternalInterface to execute.

Comment: I allow all in `Global Security Settings panel` and allow in `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust` Compile with `Access local files only` but still can't play script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `allowScriptAccess` attribute of the `<object>` tag. Set it to `always`.
2. Do you execute your page form a sandbox?

Comment: `allowScriptAccess` is set `always`.
When flash swf, recompiling without `ExternalInterface.addCallback` then page work right. 
But I need `ExternalInterface.addCallback`.

Comment: Do you try to call this page frome a server? Do you use `ExternalInterface.available`?

Comment: On server page works fine, but i need execute page offline mode. And ExternalInterface.available i use.

Comment: I allow all in `Global Security Settings panel` and allow in `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust` Compile with `Access local files only` but still can't play script.